How to not exclude items when doing a join in SQL?
I'm relatively new to SQL and trying to retrieve information from multiple tables using a join, but some items are being excluded from the query.
Here are the tables:
accounts:
account_id | account_holder | balance
-------------------------------------
1          | John Doe       | 1000.00
2          | Jane Smith     | 500.00
3          | Alice Johnson  | 2000.00

transactions:
transaction_id | account_id | amount | transaction_date
--------------------------------------------------------
1              | 1          | -500.00| 2024-04-01
2              | 1          | -200.00| 2024-04-05
3              | 2          | -100.00| 2024-04-02

My query:
SELECT a.account_id, a.account_holder, SUM(t.amount) AS total_transactions
FROM accounts a
JOIN transactions t ON a.account_id = t.account_id
GROUP BY a.account_id, a.account_holder;

However, this is my result
account_id | account_holder | total_transactions
-----------------------------------------------
1          | John Doe       | -700.00
2          | Jane Smith     | -100.00

"Alice Johnson" is missing from the result set because it hasn't had any transactions yet. How can I include all accounts, even if they don't have any transactions?
Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The Oracle documentation has a section about joins - "An outer join returns all rows that satisfy the join condition and also returns some or all of those rows from one table for which no rows from the other satisfy the join condition."

What you need here is an outer join, specifically a left outer join, which will include all rows from the accounts table regardless of whether there are matching rows in the transactions table.
You can modify your query to use a left outer join like this:
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON a.account_id = t.account_id

